# Spark: function to print RDD[A]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am writing a function which receives an RDD and a number integer `n`, and prints the `n` elements of the received RDD.

The RDD parameter hasn't a predetermined type and, using pattern matching, I wanted to print in a different way depending on the RDD.

For instance, if I have this: `myRDD:RDD[(String, Array[String])]`. When I call `printRddContent(myRDD)`, I would like to print it in this way (outside a function, this works well):

```
anRdd.map { case (a, arr) => (a, arr.toList) }.collect().take(n).foreach(println)
```

And so on, with different patterns.

So far, this is my code:

```
  def printRddContent[A](anRdd: RDD[A], n: Int) = {  
    anRdd match {
      case r1: RDD[(String, Array[String])] => anRdd.map { case (a, arr) => (a, arr.List) }.take(n).foreach(println)
      case _ => "case clause"
    }
  }
```

But the `.toList` shows a message: `Cannot resolve symbol toList`. I don't understand why this is not working inside the function.

Comment: Why don't you just do the following : def printRddContent[A](anRdd: RDD[A], n: Int) = anRdd.take(n).foreach(println) ?

Comment: You are missing a default case clause for your match statement. Also, what's the point of converting an `Array` to `List` and then just `collect`ing it?

Comment: @mahmoudmehdi I did it, but when I have RDD[(String, Array[String])] I don't see the content of each element of the Array[String]

Comment: @philantrovert you are right about the `collect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution based on the code you provided :

```
  def printRddContent[A](anRdd: RDD[A], n: Int) = {
    anRdd match {
      case r1: RDD[(String, Array[String])] => r1.asInstanceOf[RDD[(String, Array[String])]].map { case (a, arr) => (a, arr.toList)}.take(n).foreach(println)
      case _ => "case clause"
   }
 }
```

In this case, it's safe to use `asInstanceOf` since we have already checked that the RDD corresponds perfectly to the type (via the pattern matching)

Comment: When I compile, I get: `non-variable type argument (String, Array[String]) in type pattern org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure`. But, despite that, the code works! (remember my code uses Array[String] instead of Array[Int])

Comment: My bad, I was checking on a different RDD. I made the update.
If it solves your issue can you please validate the answer ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry, your answer is validated. Thanks! I'm curious about the warning when I've compiled, do you know the reason of it?

Comment: Yes, that's totally normal, it says that the RDD you provided is going to be treated in the last case which is (case _ => "case clause").
We were providing an RDD[String, Array[String]], and that case wasn't treated in the first solution (before edit).